# Grounding & Decoupling

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I found an exchange on decoupling and grounding on this forum very interesting and informative. I think I have understood the requirements for decoupling:

- Mount the decoupling capacitor close to the power supply pins;
- Keep the track length small.

However, I am not clear on the grounding techniques commented on by Olin and others, particularly with regard to EMI and EMC.

I have designed a mixed signal ckt to measure electricity consumption in multiple ckts in an industrial distribution board. This uses a PIC24FJ256GB406 MCU. I am operating this at 8 MHz. The only communication is by UART to an RS485 transceiver and by SPI for analog ICs, FRAM and a TFT display. These communications would happen only at 4 MHz (half of 8 MHZ for MCU).

The whole system is housed in a plastic enclosure but it would always be mounted inside a distribution board whose enclosure is made of steel. I hope it would act as Faraday cage and I should not an issue with radiated RF.

I have decided to use 6 layer boards for the analog and digital boards. Thus the analog and digital ckts are physically separated. Only some nodes are connected between the two. Most are for power supply and some for SPI.

Can someone advise what strategy I should use for:

a. Deciding what layers are used for what;
b. Power and ground planes;
c. Strategy for GND for EMC requirements that are mainly for EST protection.

I know that opinions vary quite a lot on grounding techniques. I have bought a book called System Level ESD Co-Design. I have a good understanding of the EMC requirements and their application to my ckt design.

I have Target3001 for doing the layout and I shall be learning that. In the mean time, I have made the layout in DraftSight for both PCBs to achieve a very compact size. I have decided to use 100 nF, 100 V decoupling capacitors in 0402 size.

Comment: I read that exchange just now as well, it was good. Your question would be improved by a link to that exchange.

Comment: "EST protection" out of curiosity and lack of knowledge, what is EST?

Answer (score 0):

A good reference on EMI noise management is available from Murata: https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/emc/emifil/c39e.ashx (PDF doc.) This tome includes tips for optimal placement, component selection, routing, etc.

As for your board, it's pretty low performance. You could easily do it on 4 layers, as:

- top: signal
- inner: ground
- inner: power
- bottom: signal

Try not to change layers for your signals. If you do, make sure you include a bypass cap nearby to provide an AC return path.

EMI suppression is addressed in several ways:

- minimize loop area
- control edge rates
- if needed, suppress noise sources with filters

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions.  I have decided to use 6 layer PCB, mainly to achieve compact layout by running some signal tracks on an inner layer.  If so, what would be the most ideal allocation of layers?

Comment: @GGRUK usually the same as 4-layer, with the two extra added in the middle as signal routing. So, sig-GND-sig-sig-VCC-sig. In my experience, there's not much value to this as thru-vias eat up all your space (across all layers!) on a very dense design anyway; but maybe I'm a bit more fanatical with resolving routes than most. I think 6-8 layers would mainly be an improvement for high density components, and with blind/buried vias an option (costs extra). 6 layer will certainly be faster to finish an initial design though.

Comment: Regarding bypass caps -- if you only have one VCC across the board, it doesn't really matter where you put caps, not at these rates (sub GHz) and impedances anyway. If you have several supplies, divide up the layer with fills/polys, and prioritize caps near their furthest extents, or where buses cross between them, and yeah, probably still at major components.

Comment: Many thanks Tim. I have managed to have only one Vdd of 3.3V.  This derived from Power Supply ckt using TI TPS5401.  This ckt is in the Analog PCB at the bottom. The digital ckt is at the top.  These two PCBs are connected together, within the Meter with a 20 way Ribbon Cable.  Am using only through hole vias.  Do you have any views on providing a separate GND for EMC and connect it to main PCB GND only at one point>